# clickable logo link in header

Tags: css

I want to add my clickable company logo to the header, which will redirect them to homepage. I tried this, but it makes the whole header clickable.

```
<div id="header">
    <a style="display:block" href="profile.php" >
        <label>
            <img src="images/logo.png" height="50x" width="180px" />
        </label>
    </a>
</div>
```

I have added the CSS associated with it:

```
div#header a
{
 position:fixed;
 height:40px;margin:0;width:100%;
 padding-left:30px;background: #00BFFF
 }
```

Comment: That is a side effect of `display: block`. Any good reason for using it?

Comment: I tried removing it... nothing happens!

Answer (score 1):

Use `CSS`.

Don't use `INLINE CSS STYLE`. Instead create css file and paste code and include it in page.

```
<style type="text/css">

    div.header
    {
        display: block;
        height: 40px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
    }
    div#header a img
    {
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .header .logo
    {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        padding: 4px 3px;
    }
    img
    {
        border: 0 none;
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>

<div class="header">
    <a href="action.php" class="logo">
        <img title="Title" alt="Alter" src="img/4.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: @SalmanA don't just comment,try your hand on it, copy paste this code and run it...its solution too..

Comment: can you please show us other css associated with it.. because i got it working here..may be other css making effect here

Comment: I mean you've removed the `img` tag altogether. May be it was required.

Comment: I have added the CSS part... Have a look

Comment: div#header a
 {
  position:fixed;
  height:40px;margin:0;width:100%;
  padding-left:30px;
  background: #00BFFF;
  
 }
 div#header a img
 {
  cursor:pointer;
 } its already click able.

Comment: now have a look at it i m sure now its done...i have cross checked it...see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Please remove **display: block** from anchor :-

```
<div id="header">
    <a href="profile.php" ><label><img src="images/logo.png" height="50x" width="180px" /></label></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I removed that, still the problem exists

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 </style> 
 div#header 
         {
         position:fixed;
        height:40px;margin:0;width:100%;
        padding-left:30px;background: #00BFFF
       }
</style> 


<div id="header">
      <a s href="profile.php" >  <img src="slider-button-left.png" height="50x" width="180px" /></a>
</div>
```